# Modal view is resized in ios 6.0 and tool bar is in the middle of the view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, modalviewcontroller

My modal view is resized and the toolbar is in the middle of my modal view and my  buttons are outside the view only in iOS 6 but the same code is working well in iOS 5.

here is my code snippet:

```
ModalViewController *viewController = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalView" bundle:nil];
    viewController.delegate = self;

    viewController.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    viewController.modalTransitionStyle =   UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    int x = (frame.size.width - 470 )/2;
    int y = (frame.size.height - 420 )/2;
    CGRect r = CGRectMake(x,
                          y,
                          470, 420);

    r = [self.view convertRect:r toView:viewController.view.superview.superview];
    viewController.view.superview.frame = r;
    [viewController release];
```

Anyone can Suggest any idea ? I don't understand what was the problem.

Comment: Still I did not find the solution. Any one can help me ?

Comment: Provide us screen shot of both iOS 5 and iOS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, by changing the

```
viewController.modalTransitionStyle =   UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

Comment: +1 for coming back and writing an answer to your old question.